# incorrect labels when using DeepSORT tracker

Tags: object-tracking, yolov7

I'm facing an issue while using DeepSORT tracker with my custom trained yolov7 model.

Initially I have trained my object detection model and now I want it to track also. I have downloaded files for DeepSORT tracker. But when I use tracker with with my trained weights, it detects and track the objects correctly but incorrect labels(default yolov7 labels i.e person, bicycle) appear on the detected objects. Can someone help me with this problem